# How to handle missing xml node in excel macro

Tags: xml, excel, vba, macros

I am using ms excel for macro written in vb. I am reading xml file, looping through and few nodes as missing. see the xml example below :

```
<document>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
    <age></age>
  </element>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
  </element>
</document>
```

For some reason If age = Nothing Then is not working. I am getting "Object doesn't support property or method" on Set age line. See my macro code example below.

```
Sub TestXML()
Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E").Clear

Dim XDoc As Object
Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

XDoc.async = False
XDoc.validateOnParse = False
XDoc.Load ("C:\MyUnzipFolder\XML_test.XML")

Set fname= XDoc.SelectNodes("/Document/element/fname/text()") 
Set age = XDoc.SelectNodes("/Document/element/age/")

If age Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("element not found.")
    Else
        MsgBox ("element found.")
End If

Set XDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All paths that end in "element/age" and start with "document":

```
Dim ages As IXMLDOMSelection
Set ages = XDoc.SelectNodes("/document//element/age")
```

---

After reading your comments:

```
' Add reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0

Sub TestXML()

    Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    XDoc.async = False
    XDoc.validateOnParse = True

    If Not XDoc.Load("c:\MyUnzipFolder\XML_test.XML") Then
        MsgBox XDoc.parseError.reason, vbOKOnly, "Error " & XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' all paths that end in element
    Dim elements As IXMLDOMSelection
    Set elements = XDoc.SelectNodes("//element")

    Dim element As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim age As IXMLDOMElement

    ' loop through each element and try getting its age
    Dim r As Long
    For Each element In elements
        r = r + 1
        Set age = element.SelectSingleNode("age")
        If Not age Is Nothing Then
            ' element has age sub element, print its text
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value = age.Text
        Else
            ' if nothing then keep cell blank
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value = "blank"
        End If
    Next element

    Set XDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

> XML_test.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
    <age>10</age>
  </element>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
  </element>
  <element>
    <age>40</age>
    <fname></fname>
  </element>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
    <age>20</age>
  </element>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
  </element>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
  </element>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
  </element>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
    <age>30</age>
  </element>
  <element>
    <fname></fname>
  </element>
</document>
```

> Result

[image]

Comment: still can get it to work. I tried your earlier suggestion as well no luck. I am trying to print the value - age in spreadsheet column. if nothing then keep cell blank..

Comment: done another test. i tried on error resume next. it fill fname column 100 rows and age node stops filling at 80 (only one node is missing). technical age loop should only skip one row then start populating. but its fillings blank in rest 20 after error. any more ideas?

Comment: @Jag - did you remove `/` after `age` in XPath in your code? Not sure if it causes this, but just in case...